# Is using double class inherit can be dangerous?

Tags: php, class, extends, inheritance

I am using this kind of model:

- class A extends class B
- class C extends class A

example as short piece of my code:

```
class InterfaceController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function getRole() {
        $userLogin = $this->getAuthService()->getIdentity();
        if ($userLogin != null && $userLogin != "")
        {
            $userData = $this->getUsersLoginTable()->getUserByLogin($userLogin);
            if ($userData) 
            {
                $role = $userData->user_Permissions;
            }
            else
            {
                $role = null;
            }
        }
        return $this->role;
    }    
}

class PostsController extends InterfaceController
{
    public function postsMainViewAction() {
       $layout = $this->layout();
       $layout->setTemplate('mainSite/layout');
       $view = new ViewModel();
       $view->setTemplate('Posts/posts/index');
       return array(
           'role' => $this->getRole()
       );
    }
}
```

Example is based on Zend Framework 2 application
My question however is still more general about OOP model

Question is as follows:
"Can this use of extend classes negative influence to application performance ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weakest spot in the example you give is that you don't show any methods (at the time I answered the question). Without any methods given, we can only say that it is superfluous.

If you wouldn't regard superfluous as a problem, then there is no problem.

As there ain't no logic involved as well, the logic can not be flawed by that inheritance you describe.

Hope this helps. In other cases, e.g. if your classes actually have methods, look for:

- Composition over Inheritance
- Liskov Substitution Principle

Comment: Composition over Inheritance found in Wikipedia resolved my problem. Its looks like: "Classes may achieve polymorphic behaviour and code reuse by containing other classes that implement the desired functionality instead of through inheritance". And its all about, I can use "double extends" in the way is presented above because it is another technique of OOP and its not any "abomination" :) Thanks